# Use of Acronyms in the thesis

Tags: thesis

I don't want to use acronyms in my thesis. but i have table which i am showing some data. I have to put acronyms in the table to make it inside the width. So i am using acronyms only in the table area. Can i do it in the table if i want and not at any other place.
for example Let say

I am measuring speed(S) test(T) for instance .

and then in the table can i have  S , T ?

Note speed and test are not first occurrences. I only want to use acronyms in the table and not any other part of the thesis. Is is ok to do that in thesis ?

Comment: Depends on your convention. Your thesis should be accessible to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

It happens quite often that you need abbreviations only within a figure. In this case, you will usually just note the abbreviations in the figure caption.

So you could caption your table something like "Table 4: Some data showing the influence of speed (S) on test (T)."